# SQLPLUS prevents while loop from ending

Tags: bash, sqlplus

I have a function that, in a loop, calls another function that executes an sql.
If the sql is a file, it only executes the 1st sql, but, if the sql is embedded, it finishes the loop. Example:

```
function conciliateFile {

### NOT WORKING
    sqlplus -S -L ${BBDD_CHAIN} @ ${HOME}/tmp/prueba.sql

### WORKING
#sqlplus -S -L ${BBDD_CHAIN} <<EOF
#set serveroutput on size 1000000
#set linesize 350
#DECLARE
#result_code VARCHAR2(4);
#result_description VARCHAR2(500);
#BEGIN
#DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HELLO');
#END;
#\
#exit;
#EOF
}



funcion mainFunction {
    NUM_FILES=$(find ${SQL_PATH} -type f -name "${PATTERN}*sql" |wc -l)
    COUNTER=1
    find ${SQL_PATH} -type f -name "${PATTERN}*sql" | sort -t"_" -k 2 -n | while read CURRENT_TMP_SQL_FILE; do
        CURRENT_TMP_SQL_OUT_FILE=${CURRENT_TMP_SQL_FILE}_out
        CURRENT_TMP_SQL_ERR_FILE=${CURRENT_TMP_SQL_FILE}_err
        echo "Conciliating file ${COUNTER} out of ${NUM_FILES}"
        conciliateFile
        COUNTER=$(expr ${COUNTER} + 1)
}

# Main
#split files
mainFunction
```

And the output would be something like this:

**NOT WORKING (executing sql file)**

```
"Conciliating file 1 out of 3"
```

**WORKING OPTION (executing embedded sql)**

```
"Conciliating file 1 out of 3"
"Conciliating file 2 out of 3"
"Conciliating file 3 out of 3"
```

Any suggestions on this issue???

Comment: This also works:
```sqlplus -S -L ${BBDD_CHAIN} < ${HOME}/tmp/prueba.sql ```

Answer (score 0):

Your script prueba.sql must end with an exit - otherwise sqlplus will not terminate execution

Comment: It does end with "exit;"